# Passing (unescaped/unencoded) JSON string as command line parameter in .net core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, escaping, command-line-arguments

I've read a lot of posts on this topic here by now but none of them seemed able to solve my problem.

I want to pass a JSON string as a parameter to the command line. (The JSON string passed must not be altered, e.g. by escaping all the quotes or converting it to base 64. Wrapping it as a whole into let's say """ would be okay though).

How do I get the whole JSON as one string out of the `string[] args` variable?

Example:

```
myprogram.exe myfunction {"Id": 0, "Some": "thing"}
```

Everything I tried yet ended up in a .net core string without double quotes or multiple entries in `string[] args`

Thanks for help!

Comment: JSON is not appropriate for parameter passing.

Comment: Ok. Then I will try to find another solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can pass a JSON as parameter in command line, it's just a string as any other parameter. The issue here is that anything between double quotes (") will be interpreted as a single parameter. This is the way command line allows to have parameters with spaces or other special characters.

To use a JSON, just put it between double quotes and escape any double quote inside it by adding a backlash:

```
myprogram.exe myfunction "{\\"Id\\": 0, \\"Some\\": \\"thing\\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As JSON seems to be inappropriate for parameter passing I will read it from file. And pass only the file path as command line argument.